# MySQL Workbench 5.2.47 CE: EDIT database.table command doesn't work

Tags: mysql-workbench

When I type the following command on the SQL editor I get Error Code: 1064
      `EDIT my_database.my_table;`

but the commands
      `SELECT * from my_database.my_table;`
works fine.

Thanks

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The EDIT command was only a temporary workaround until we had proper parsing in place to determine if a query result can be edited or not. This keyword is no longer supported since a year or more.